# How can i create one list from tow related table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

Hi I have model with to table and a one to many relationship between
Order and status

i want to show a list with all of properties in order and the last Title in status according to  Order id in order
how could i get it?
thank you

this is my code :

```
    namespace Pur.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public partial class Order
    {


        public int OrdeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UserID { get; set; }

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }


        public string Description { get; set; }


        public int Quantity { get; set; }


        public string Unit { get; set; }


        public string Priority { get; set; }


        public string Department { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Status> Status { get; set; }


    }
}
```

and the other:

```
namespace Pur.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public partial class Status
    {
        public int StatusId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int OrderID { get; set; }


        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StatusDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: any body can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create join query and then pass it to a new model

```
var query = your query
var Lists = db.Database.SqlQuery<OrderModel>(query);
```

Comment: what is the best join query for my question 
I want to show all data from order and the last or first value in status table 
thank you

Comment: SELECT  O.OrdeId,S.StatusId
  FROM Status s RIGHT OUTER JOIN order O ON (O.OrdeId=S.OrderID)
  where S.StatusId = (Select top 1 StatusId  from Status ORDER BY S.StatusIDESC)

Comment: its useful to use in sql sever and not for C#
but i need a linq code to use in asp.net mvc

Comment: You can use this query in (var query = your query
var Lists = db.Database.SqlQuery<OrderModel>(query);) in mvc or use it in dapper